# Правильно ли расставлены запятые в данных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, ссп

1. К делам Чацкий относится серьезно и не привык смешивать работу с весельем.
2. Его огорчает мысль, что русское дворянство ориентировано на запад, и образование в России не является глубоким, профессиональным.
3. Важны для него родственные связи, и продвигает по службе он лишь близких и дальних родственников.

Answer (score 4):

Допущена только одна ошибка во втором предложении: запятая перед союзом ***и*** не нужна.

***Его огорчает мысль,** что русское дворянство ориентировано на запад **и** [что] образование в России не является глубоким, профессиональным.*

Два придаточных предложения, соединенных союзом ***и***, являются однородными и относятся к одной общей части – главному предложению.

См.: [Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139) (справочник Розенталя).

Comment: Чегой-то никто не поддерживает... Исправляю эту странность.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо, Римма!  Вообще в последнее время активность голосования очень снизилась... Ответ о "стесняться перед кем" как-то обошёл меня стороной, сейчас отметил.